# Why is my Android SwipeRefreshLayout not refreshing?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have found many articles on implementing Android's SwipeRefreshLayout [this being the one I followed](http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout), and they all say it is very simple, however I cannot seem to get mine to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
package myPackage;

public class MyClass extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor dataCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;

    private ListView rowOfDataListView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_awesome_layout, container, false);
        rowOfDataListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.row_of_data);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_container);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);

        if(getArguments() != null) {
            idNumber = getArguments().getString("id");
        }

        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor(idNumber);

        String[] fromColumns = {"column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.column1_textview, R.id.column2_textview, R.id.column3_textview, R.id.column4_textview, R.id.column5_textview, R.id.column6_textview};

        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_of_data_layout, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        rowOfDataListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My data originally displays correctly, but the refresh does not refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you're updating the data onRefresh.  I think you should separate the code which builds the View into a new method, call it in your onViewCreated method, and then call it again in onRefresh.  Otherwise, onRefresh gets triggered, but it doesn't "DO" anything.

```
package myPackage;

public class MyClass extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private Cursor dataCursor;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter mySimpleCursorAdapter;

    private ListView rowOfDataListView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mySwipeRefreshLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_awesome_layout, container, false);
        rowOfDataListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.row_of_data);
        mySwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_container);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        methodToBuildTheData();

        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                methodToBuildTheData();
            }
        });
    }

    private void methodToBuildTheData() {
        if(getArguments() != null) {
            idNumber = getArguments().getString("id");
        }

        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

        dataCursor = myDBHelper.getDataCursor(idNumber);

        String[] fromColumns = {"column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6"};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.column1_textview, R.id.column2_textview, R.id.column3_textview, R.id.column4_textview, R.id.column5_textview, R.id.column6_textview};

        mySimpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row_of_data_layout, dataCursor, fromColumns, toViews, 0);

        rowOfDataListView.setAdapter(mySimpleCursorAdapter);

        myDBHelper.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, that just worked perfectly! Thank you. I was confused about updating the data on refresh as well. I didn't see anything like that in the examples either, or I completely missed it. Thanks again for the suggestion of breaking my view build code into a new method.

Comment: @Brian, no problem at all.  I know I struggled with the SwipeRefreshLayout for a while too.  It's pretty awesome how it works though.  Glad it worked for you